# CUPS web interface on YOCTO

Tags: yocto, cups

I have a yocto image into which I have included the [CUPS](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-extended/cups) package (using `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`).

While running the OS, I couldn't find the cups file in `/etc/init.d`.

I started cups using `cupsd`. When I tried accessing the web interface using `localhost:631`, I got a `not found error`. The console shows that it is not able to load resources on any of those URLS:

http://localhost:631/cups.css

http://localhost:631/

http://localhost:631/favicon.ico

The html and related files seem to be listed in the `cups.inc` [file](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-extended/cups/cups.inc). Are there additional configuration changes that need be made before doing the YOCTO build or on the CUPS setup?

Since I am very new to yocto and developing in a linux environment, I am not sure if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made good research pointing to the recipe and were actually close to find the solution.

[In the recipe](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-extended/cups/cups.inc), you can read:

```
# Remove sysinit script and symlinks if sysvinit is not in DISTRO_FEATURES
if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES','sysvinit','false','true',d)}; then
    rm -rf ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/
    rm -rf ${D}${sysconfdir}/rc*
fi
```

Is `sysvinit` in your `DISTRO_FEATURES`?

If you don't know you can do

```
bitbake cups -e | grep "^DISTRO_FEATURES="
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, David. Yes, sysvinit is present in DISTRO_FEATURES! I didn't consciously notice this piece of code in the recipe. Also what I found is, (thanks to this - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/cups-web-interface-not-found-4175525114/),  I had access to localhost:631/admin. I could add a printer successfully by accessing this page, although I am still not able to access localhost:631.

Comment: Great! I now invite you to check open ports

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old and already has an accepted answer. Nevertheless, it may be of use for someone else facing the same problem of missing static html content of the CUPS Web interface.

The CUPS recipe packages the static web content into cups-doc.
Thus, instead of

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " cups"
```

it should be

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " cups cups-doc"
```

in your conf/local.conf. 
Then, also the files under /usr/share/doc/cups were added to the rootfs.

Check

```
# Replace <target>, <image> and <version> to match your configuration
# e.g.: raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/core-image-full-cmdline/1.0-r0

$YOUR_POKY_DIRECTORY/build/tmp/work/<target>/<image>/<version>/rootfs/usr/share/doc/cups
```

that was entirely missing before adding the cups-doc package.