# Installing cups on embedded linux using yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, cups, imx6

I would like to setup my **[slp650 printer](http://www.smart-label-printer.com/fr/)** on my **[tx6s-8035 KARO Board](https://www.karo-electronics.com/856.html?&L=1)** using yocto.
I add the [cups package](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-extended/cups/) on my local.conf and i create a recipe for the **[slp650 driver](https://github.com/paulfurley/smart-label-printer-slp-linux-driver)** that i add as a package too in my local.conf file.
The build work well and when i verify cups service afater starting kernel on my board, i realize that there is no cups service on my system. 
In the cups recipe, in **do_install task**, it precise that if there is no **sysvint** on the distro, it will remove service but in my distro, i use sysvinit. 
Anyone could help me to activate cups service on my embedded linux system?
I use [Ka-ro NXP/Freescale Yocto Project Community BSP recipe layers](https://github.com/karo-electronics/fsl-community-bsp-platform) for yocto distro krogoth.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220470/cups-web-interface-on-yocto ?

Comment: Also, see: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#new-recipe-enabling-system-services

Comment: Thanks for all !

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like this to cups bbappend file

```
inherit update-rc.d

INITSCRIPT_NAME = "cups"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "defaults"

SRC_URI += "file://cups.initd"

do_install_append () {
   install -d -m 0755 ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
   install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/cups.initd ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/cups
}
```

with cups.initd the shell script to launch cups